# Avoid Existing Items in TextBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
  Private Sub BtnMoveItemstoTemplate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnMoveItemstoTemplate.Click
    Try
        If LBMessageContents.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
            ShowMessage("Select Some Details to Send a Message")
        Else
           RTMsgContent.Text = RTMsgContent.Text & LBMessageContents.SelectedItem
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        HandleClassException(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I write a code for moving an item from ListBox to RichTextBox.

How to validate if a list item is already exist or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As vinayak, said, you can use `.contains()` to know if the text box contains the string or not

```
Private Sub BtnMoveItemstoTemplate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnMoveItemstoTemplate.Click
  Try
    If LBMessageContents.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        ShowMessage("Select Some Details to Send a Message")
    Else
        'check if the item already exists
        If RtMsgContent.Text.Contains(LBMessageContents.SelectedItem) then
            'do what you want to do if the item already exists. like showing message
            MsgBox("Error! This item already exists")
        Else
            'doesn't already exists, add to the textbox
            RTMsgContent.Text = RTMsgContent.Text & LBMessageContents.SelectedItem
        End If
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    HandleClassException(ex)
  End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution for my question.

I used the [.contains()] function to validate the text is already exists or not.

```
   Private Sub BtnMoveItemstoTemplate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnMoveItemstoTemplate.Click
    Try
    If LBMessageContents.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        ShowMessage("Select Some Details to Send a Message")
    Else

   **If RtMsgContent.Text.Contains(LBMessageContents.SelectedItem) then Exit Sub**

       RTMsgContent.Text = RTMsgContent.Text & LBMessageContents.SelectedItem
    End If

  Catch ex As Exception
    HandleClassException(ex)
  End Try
  End Sub
```